# Changing the location of a TFS build server

Tags: tfsbuild

I have installed TFS 2012 on a PC but have been asked to perform the build on a different PC.  It seems like I need the TFS administration tool on that PC for autobuilding.

Am I able to do this without installing Team Foundation Server on the, soon to be, build server?

Okay, I have been told I need to install TFS on the build PC but can select 'Build Sevices' as an option, however:

I cannot install 2012 as I get the error "Error : TF400155 : Only 64-bit versions of Windows Server are supported." but there does not seem to be an Express version of 2010.

Have I missed something? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install TFS on the build server. However, while installing choose only "Build Services", rather than the full TFS.

Comment: Thanks - now I seem to be caught in a corner. I cannot install 2012 as I get the error "Error : TF400155 : Only 64-bit versions of Windows Server are supported." but there does not seem to be an Express version of 2010. Have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, TFS2012 (including build services) can only be installed on 64-bit Windows. And you can't install TFS2010 build services and connect it to TFS2012. You'll have to re-install the build machine with 64-bit Windows - that's what I did when I hit the exact same problem.

Comment: Note: TFS 2012.2 now supports TFS 2010 Build Agents, so if your version of Windows is supported by TFS 2010 you could install the 2010 Agent on there.

Comment: Okay, without having to buy TFS 2010 and without reinstalling Windows on our wannabe build serer is there a way I can do what I have been asked to do ie have TFS 2012 on one machine and the build server on another?